# Where can I find a good GVIM cheatsheet?

Tags: vim

Can anyone recommend a GVim cheatsheet specifically for GVIM? 
Am pretty much a new user and wondering where to look for a cheatsheet?

Comment: any vim cheat will do.. what do you need which is gvim specific?

Comment: Am quite new to VIM. Any sheet will do will it? On a bit of a steep learning curve.

Comment: I have a forked branch here: https://github.com/Ramesh-X/vim-cheatsheet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif is my favourite.

Comment: Great stuff just what I was looking for Cheers for that!

Answer (score 2):

Here: https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/gvim/gvim.html

Is a tutorial and a few sheets.

Answer (score 2):

http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html

Comment: +1 - when I was learning Vim a printout of this was my constant companion.

Answer (score 0):

vimtutor is a great tutorial for beginers

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is [zapper's tipset](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Best_Vim_Tips). It's really excellent. And visit all [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) site -- there are gems there.